# What is a lightweight library for encoding HTML entities in Java?

Tags: java, html-entities

What I require is a Java method or lightweight library which will encode special characters into HTML entities. So & becomes &amp; " becomes &quot; £ becomes &pound; etc.

I say "lightweight" because all my current searching has found is the Apache Commons Lang StringEscapeUtils class, which does the job perfectly, but increases my program size from 50Kb to 350Kb.

The Apache Commons Lang library is perfect, apart from the size. So if there was a way of reducing the size (or extracting the method they use for encoding) that would be great. Otherwise, if someone has another method or library which does the same thing, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you deploy on a phone? Else, 300 KB is nothing.

Anyway, the special chars to encode are not many: `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'`. All the other characters don't need escaping if you use an encoding able to handle all the characters, like UTF-8. So building such a method yourself should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the source code of that library (StringEscapeUtils) and use the necessary source code not all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are content with *named* entities for <. >. &, " and ' and *numeric* entities (like **&#12345;**) for chars > 127, then java already knows to convert them. JTextPane handles HTML as such, as it is encoding unaware.

```
// Minimum overhead:
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setContentType("text/html");
tp.setText(html); // read?
String htmlWithEntities = tp.getText(); // Does this work?
```

Better would be using HTMLEditorKit and creating an HTMLDocument.

If you would like to avoid having a document object model, you could easily do it yourself. See JB Nizet.